# adaptive contrast image calculation

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the adaptive image contrast using the formula in matlab

```
Ca(i,j)=A*C(i,j)+(1-A)*Imax(i,j)-Imin(i,j)
```

where

```
C(i,j)=Imax(i,j)-Imin(i,j)/Imax(i,j)+Imin(i,j)

A=(Std/128)^y
```

C(i, j ) denotes the contrast of an image pixel (i, j ),Imax(i, j ) and Imin(i, j ) denote the maximum and minimum intensities within a local neighborhood windows of (i, j ), respectively, window size is

```
3.(Imax(i, j ) − Imin(i, j ))
```

refers to the local image gradient that is normalized to [0, 1].'A' is the weight between local contrast and local gradient that is controlled based on the document image statistical information."Std"denotes the document image intensity standard deviation, and 'y' is a pre-defined parameter,Parameter 'y' should be set around 1.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

With the im2col matlab function you can rearrange each pixel neighborhood into a column of a new DxN matrix, where D is the number of pixels of the neighborhood and N the number of pixels of the image. So, you could do something like:

```
%Assuming you have your image in the I variable,
%and [Dr,Dc] is the neighborhood size

[Nr,Nc] = size(I);
Inew = im2col(padarray(I,floor([Dr,Dc]/2),NaN),[Dr Dc]);
Imax = reshape( max(Inew,[],1), [Nr,Nc] );
Imin = reshape( min(Inew,[],1), [Nr,Nc] );
```

With this, you should be able to compute C and Ca normally.

Regards